# How can I combine regular expression /^1+/ and /-/g?

Tags: javascript, regex

following stuff works fine:

```
const formattedNumber = numberString.replace(/^1+/, '').replace(/-/g, '');
```

however I want to use single regular expression which handles both the cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use an [alternation `|` operator](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html):

```
const formattedNumber = numberString.replace(/^1+|-/g, '');
                                                 ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GwhjV1/2)

**Details**

- `^1+` - `1`, one or more times (`+`), from the start of the string (`^`)
- `|` - or
- `-` - a hyphen.

```js
console.log("11234-4-7-9+11111".replace(/^1+|-/g, ''));
```